# How to validate checkboxes with same css class name

Tags: jquery, validation, requiredfieldvalidator, jquery-form-validator

I have a form that contains several questions. Some of these questions are checkbox inputs.

When a form question is generated, it follows the following structure:

1. Contains the parent div `<div class="checkbox">`
2. If the checkbox is a required field (user must select at least one checkbox for that question), the parent div gets the CSS class 'required' added to the existing class.
3. When "Save Changes" button is clicked, it should search for all divs as following: `<div class="checkbox required">`
4. If that div contains at least one checkbox that is checked, it should continue to the next, and so on, finally submitting the form if no errors found.
5. If it comes across a `<div class="checkbox required">` that does NOT have any checkboxes checked, it should print an error message next to that question.

Below is the code that I have. Both of the questions are required. It's fairly close, I just can't seem to get it quite right. It seems to treat all divs with "required" class as one object, rather than as each as their own individual object in the `boxes.each` section.
Does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var boxes = $('div.checkbox.required');

        boxes.each(function(){
            if($(this).is(":checked"))
            {
                $(".error", this).hide();
                $("form").submit();
                return true;
            } else if($(this).not(":checked")) {
                $(".error", this).show().html("Please fill out all required fields");
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
    
});
```

```css
label { font-weight: bold; }
.form-horizontal label span.error { color: red; }
.form-horizontal label div.error { color: red; }
.error {
    padding: 2px;
    font-size: 15px;
    background: #FFDFDF;
    border: 1px solid #FFCACA;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox required">
<h3>Question 1</H3>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <span class="error"></span>
    <label id="8522[]">
      <input type="checkbox" class="" id="input-8522" name="8522[]" value="23606">
      Behavioral Follow-up
    </label><br>
    <label id="8522[]">
      <input type="checkbox" class="" id="input-8522" name="8522[]" value="23607">
      Medical Follow-up
    </label><br>
  </div>
</div>
<p><br></p>
<div class="checkbox required">
<h3>Question 2</H3>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <span class="error"></span>
    <label id="8524[]">
      <input type="checkbox" class="" id="input-8524" name="8524[]" value="23608">
      Mild
    </label><br>
    <label id="8524[]">
      <input type="checkbox" class="" id="input-8524" name="8524[]" value="23609" checked="checked">
      Moderate
    </label><br>
    <label id="8524[]">
      <input type="checkbox" class="" id="input-8524" name="8524[]" value="23610">
      Severe
    </label><br>
  </div>
</div>

<p><br></p>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary action-save">
<i class="fa fa-save"></i> Save changes
</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.slim.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues I see.

The first is with the line `if($(this).is(":checked"))`. `$(this)` in this block is referring to a `div.checkbox.required` since we are iterating through the list of elements that match this selector. `<div>` elements do not get the  `:checked` property, so this will always evaluate to `false`. Instead, we want to determine if the `div.checkbox.required` *contains* any `:checked` inputs. We could do that with:

```
const hasAnyChecked = $(this).find('input:checked').length > 0;
```

The next issue is that the `$("form").submit()` is *within* the `boxes.each` loop. This will not work because if, for example, the first `div.checkbox.required` contains a `:checked` input and is therefore valid, the form will be submitted before checking the remaining `div.checkbox.required` elements to determine if they too are valid. Instead, we must use a variable to track that *all* `div.checkbox.required` are in a valid state and then conditionally submit the form once the `boxes.each` loop has completed.

The code becomes:

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').on('click', function () {
    let isValid = true;

    $('div.checkbox.required').each(function () {
      const $this = $(this);
      const hasAnyChecked = $this.find('input:checked').length > 0;

      isValid = isValid && hasAnyChecked;

      if (hasAnyChecked) {
        $this.find('.error').hide();
      } else {
        $this.find('.error').text('Please fill out all required fields').show();
      }
    });

    if (isValid) {
      $("form").submit();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.form-horizontal label span.error {
  color: red;
}

.form-horizontal label div.error {
  color: red;
}

.error {
  padding: 2px;
  font-size: 15px;
  background: #FFDFDF;
  border: 1px solid #FFCACA;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox required">
  <h3>Question 1</H3>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <span class="error"></span>
    <label id="8522[]">
      <input type="checkbox" class="" id="input-8522" name="8522[]" value="23606">
      Behavioral Follow-up
    </label><br>
    <label id="8522[]">
      <input type="checkbox" class="" id="input-8522" name="8522[]" value="23607">
      Medical Follow-up
    </label><br>
  </div>
</div>
<p><br></p>
<div class="checkbox required">
  <h3>Question 2</H3>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <span class="error"></span>
    <label id="8524[]">
      <input type="checkbox" class="" id="input-8524" name="8524[]" value="23608">
      Mild
    </label><br>
    <label id="8524[]">
      <input type="checkbox" class="" id="input-8524" name="8524[]" value="23609" checked="checked">
      Moderate
    </label><br>
    <label id="8524[]">
      <input type="checkbox" class="" id="input-8524" name="8524[]" value="23610">
      Severe
    </label><br>
  </div>
</div>

<p><br></p>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary action-save">
  <i class="fa fa-save"></i> Save changes
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works exactly as it should. More importantly, I learned some valuable lessons here. I can't thank you enough, this has been driving me nuts!

Comment: @AndrewRout : You are welcome! If my post was helpful to you then I would appreciate you marking it as the Accepted Answer.